# Number of solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a polynomial in integers $\psi (x)$ of degree $k$.
Consider the number of solutions 
$$
\psi(z) \equiv u (\mod p^r)
$$

with
$$
(\psi'(z),p)=1. 
$$

I was wondering how can I show that the number of solutions is $O(1)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what Hensel's lifting lemma is?

Comment: Right! Yes, I do. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at most $\max(k,p)\leq p$ solutions to $\psi (z) \equiv u \pmod{p}$.

Consider lifting solutions from $p^r$ to $p^{r+1}$.
Hensel's lifting lemma tells us that if $z$ is a solution $\pmod{p^r}$, then there exists a unique solution $z^*$ in the higher modulus power, such that $z^* \equiv z \pmod{p^r}$ if $\psi'(z) \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p^r} $.

Hence, there are at most $p$ solutions where $\psi'(z) \neq 0$, and thus there are at most $p$ solutions to $(\psi'(z), p) = 1$.